# Using User built in model in Django

Tags: python, django, model

I am trying to save the username of the current logged in user from the django built in User model.

model.py

```
class Notes(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note = models.CharField(max_length = 100000000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.note
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def saveNote(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        note = request.POST['note']
        print(request.user.username)
        note = Notes(username=request.user.username ,note = request.POST["note"])
        note.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

But this shows an error.
I want to save the current user in the Notes table along with the note.
How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: you're saving a ForeignKey to the user, so your Note's model field should better be called `user` (not `username`) which will make it easier for you to discover your error: you need to pass a `User` object (`request.user`) to the `Notes` initialiser, not a string (not `request.user.username`).

Comment: And in general when you ask a question on SO, don't say "it gives me an error". Always show the exact error you're getting.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thank you for taking your time to review the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are few errors in your code.

first this

```
username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

should be

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and

```
note = models.CharField(max_length = 100000000) charfield can hold 255 char
```

so you need

```
note = models.TextField()



  @login_required
    def saveNote(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            note = request.POST['note']
            print(request.user.username)
            note = Notes(username=request.user #user=request.user if you change your model field name
 ,note = note)
                note.save()
            return redirect('/')
```